# AngularJS filter orderBy - numbers appear to be considered as string

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have an array of objects which is obtained from JSON in PHP and <strike>all properties come back as a string (in quotes)</strike> the property required comes back as an int from the API.

I have a particular property let's say 'value' <strike>which I convert to integer type (using parseInt())</strike> for each object in the array. I want to apply the orderBy $filter on this property but the order comes back in lexicographical order ( i.e. 9 then 88 then 8... etc) which as far as I'm aware means 'value' is being considered as a string.

The way I apply the filter is as follows:

```
scope.sortedItems = $filter('orderBy')(scope.sortedItems, sortItems, true);
```

which uses the function sortItems:

```
var sortItems = function(item) {
    return [item[scope.orderProp], mapping[item.item_rarity]];
};
```

to apply secondary ordering as well as the primary.

I'm confused as I've also run isNaN on each property everytime the filter is applied and for each object, it comes back as false (is a number). There are some null values but I would assume this doesn't affect anything?

edit: modified the returned JSON to return integers but still no luck.

Comment: Seems like you're missing some brackets in there.

Comment: @elclanrs sorry that's just a typo - fixed.

Comment: If you can - just go through the data in php and convert there all data into int., or even if you said you converted them on js side - some may still be non converted somewhere (like you converted them once, btu later use oryginal values).

Comment: @Seti I considered doing this but with PDO it seems like there is no good way to achieve this.

Comment: @Seti I've done this outside of PDO. Do you think it's a good idea to always provide the JSON as its actual type?

Comment: I often do that. I use PP (or other language if needed) and then prepares the output with correct types and so on. Its usually very fast (depending on number of changes you need to do). But its easy in php just `*1`

Comment: @Seti Alright, thanks. Unfortunately this didn't fix the Angular Issue.

Comment: http://www.newyyz.com/blog/2013/11/13/angularjs-custom-orderby-function/  according to this - function used there must return postion in the ordered list.... yours returns array... (so NaN).